# Is there a way to use FILTER with multiple Sheets containing a specific phrase in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, concatenation, spreadsheet

I will try to be as clear as possible. Here is the example piece: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UcQOAcXdVMdHDLLPS8pFuIS8UieycVR4g-BfqJcnfho/edit)

What I want to happen is that the Filter formula will search for any Sheet containing “Form Responses” and then display the results. You can see on the Current sheet how I’ve been doing, but this is more tedious and leads to issues of the first formula begins to overwrite the next one, etc. On the Wanted tab, I’ve laid out how I imagine it and put a note in A7. Any help offered is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can get started with this script:

```
  function getSheetResponses(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Wanted");
  var getCellValue = sheet.getRange("A7").getValue(); //Gets the name of your designated sheet on "Wanted Sheet" cell "A7"
  var getName = ss.getSheetByName(getCellValue);
  var getNameValue = getName.getRange(2,5,getName.getLastRow(),1).getValues(); //Gets all the values of Column E on any defined sheet names based on getCellValue
  var datalength = getNameValue.length;
  Logger.log(datalength);
  
  sheet.getRange(8,6,datalength,1).setValues(getNameValue); //Puts the data on Wanted Sheet Column F 

}
```

What this does is it gets the sheet name on cell A7, and populates the data on Column F row 8 on the "Wanted" sheet like so:

[image]

Now, the data it populates on the "Wanted" sheet came from Form Responses 1 based on the sample piece you have provided:

[image]

If ever you would want to relocate which specific row or column the data would be pasted on "Wanted" Sheet. You can refer to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) on how to modify the rows and columns on `sheet.getRange()`

**Reference:**

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns

Comment: I appreciate the response! My experience with AppScript is kind of limited. I’m a bit confused what this script is doing or trying to do. Can you kind of walk me through it? I understand what the functions are doing (I think) but why A7, why Col. E, and why is “wanted” in the formula? Sorry if it’s too many questions! Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Bysshe I edited my post above, and all of these examples are based on the Current Tab you have provided, but if there are any misunderstandings on how you would want the data to populate, let me know.